# Do ros wiki provides all the tecnical information about ros?

Tags: ros, 3d-object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can i learn everything about ros in ros wiki only?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234663/do-ros-wiki-provides-all-the-tecnical-information-about-ros?/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2016-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer: No

Long answer: Depends on the respective package, as well as what you mean by "learn everything".
The wiki is a community effort and thus the respective packages wiki pages are more or less up-to-date.
To really learn ROS, you definitely need to program ROS nodes, and you need to understand the theory behind the higher level functionalities (navigation, manipulation, object recognition) from a more scientific point of view to really know how to use it.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-05-19**:
thanks for the valuable feedback, mig. i really apriciate your feedback.